# Using .lyr symbology in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, symbology, layer-file

I'm trying to set the symbology of a raster output in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS 10.1.

I've followed the guidelines by creating the .lyr file and the adding it to the Layer Symbology tab of the Output properties.

The model works fine but for some reason the output will not take in the style from the pre-defined .lyr file and the output still have default symbology when I run it.

Is there anything else missing here?

Comment: I am assuming you are using ArcGIS? Could you confirm this and the version please as it could help potential answerers?

Comment: Are you adding the output to display? Just setting the symbology won't necessarily add it to display. Also try setting it to be a parameter?

Comment: OK - when Add to Display and Model Parameter are 'on' it works. Thanks. Is there a way of displaying the output without having Model Parameter on. I don't want my GUI giving the user the choice of output name or destination.

Comment: Ok just try add to display, see if that works. I've come across this issue about making an output a parameter when you don't really want it to be. Never found a solution.